# Javascript - Remove attributes that contains similar names

Tags: javascript

I have a json where I have similar attributes like:

```
{
  "audio_file1": "...",
  "audio_file2": "...",
  "audio_file3": "...",
  "audio_file4": "...",
  ...
 }
```

I'm trying to remove all attributes `audio_fileX`. My first try was using a `for/loop` in a function that receives the array, initial position and maximum number of file.

What is the most eficient way to remove attributes like `audio_fileX`?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overhead using `spread syntax ...` from other answers, I recommend you to use the function `Object.assign`.

```js
const obj = {  "audio_file1": "...",  "audio_file2": "...", "audio_file3": "...",  "audio_file4": "...",  "myown": "Ele"},
      start = "audio_file",
      result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, c) =>  c.startsWith(start) ? a : Object.assign(a, {[c]: obj[c]}), Object.create(null));
      
console.log(result);
```

Comment: https://jsperf.com/object-assign-vs-spreadcvs This is actually slower than using spread.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the properties to a new object, each iteration of the reduce either spreads the property into a new result if the property doesn't start with the string or it return the previous result without the property.

removeBetterPerformance does the same thing but mutates the previous result for better performance but sacrifices functional purity. This is unnecessary for a small number of properties.

```js
let obj = {
  audio_file1: "...",
  audio_file2: "...",
  audio_file3: "...",
  audio_file4: "...",
  other: "..."
 };
 
 const remove = (obj, str) =>
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce(
      (result, property) => (property.startsWith(str) ? result : { ...result, [property]: obj[property] }),
      {}
    );
 
 console.log(remove(obj, 'audio_file'));
 
 const removeBetterPerformance = (obj, str) =>
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((result, property) => {
      if (!property.startsWith(str)) {
        result[property] = obj[property];
      }
      return result;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Probably the OP wants `startswith`.

Comment: The downside to this is that the spread operator `...` will be copying properties over and over. `Object.assign` in the reducer is probably more efficient.

Comment: The spread operator is functionally pure, Object.assign is not. Performance will only be an issue on a huge number of properties.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's a bit tough to tell if you're working with JSON (as you say) or a JavaScript object.

For this answer, I'll assume it's JSON that you've imported one way or another and have converted it to a JavaScript object through `JSON.parse()`.

So getting that out of the way, you're left with:

```
const obj = {
    audio_file1 : "...",
    audio_file2 : "...",
    audio_file3 : "...",
    audio_file4 : "...",
    ...
};
```

From here, you want to go through the object and find the keys that contain the string 'audio_file' and remove them from the object.

Below is a snippet demonstrated how this can be accomplished with ES6 methods:

```js
const obj = {
  audio_file1 : "...",
  audio_file2 : "...",
  audio_file3 : "...",
  audio_file4 : "...",
};

for (let key in obj) {

  if (key.startsWith('audio_file')) {
  
    delete(obj[key]);
    
  }

}

console.log(obj);
```

For a brief explanation of this, the code goes through each key of your object and checks if it starts with 'audio_file' and if so, it deletes it. You can see at the end the console logs an empty object as all of the current keys start with that string.